# Error 'AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute' while groupby functionality on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe `news_count`. Here are its column names, from the output of `news_count.columns.values`:

```
 [('date', '') ('EBIX UW Equity', 'NEWS_SENTIMENT_DAILY_AVG') ('Date', '')
  ('day', '') ('month', '') ('year', '')]
```

I need to `groupby` by year and month and sum values of `'NEWS_SENTIMENT_DAILY_AVG'`. Below is code I tried, but neither work:

#### Attempt 1

```
news_count.groupby(['year','month']).NEWS_SENTIMENT_DAILY_AVG.values.sum()

'AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute'
```

#### Attempt 2

```
news_count.groupby(['year','month']).iloc[:,1].values.sum()

AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'iloc' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

Input data:

```
      ticker       date           EBIX UW Equity    month    year
      field             NEWS_SENTIMENT_DAILY_AVG
         0      2007-05-25                   0.3992      5       2007
         1      2007-11-06                   0.3936      11      2007 
         2      2007-11-07                   0.2039      11      2007
         3      2009-01-14                   0.2881       1      2014
```

Comment: And did you try `news_count.groupby(['year','month']).NEWS_SENTIMENT_DAILY_AVG.sum()`?

Comment: The problem is it not identifying the `NEWS_SENTIMENT_DAILY_AVG` column. Error message - `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'NEWS_SENTIMENT_DAILY_AVG'`

Comment: Are you working with a multi index of columns?

Comment: Yes. But I did reset_index(). Afterwards my second column is named `('EBIX UW Equity', 'NEWS_SENTIMENT_DAILY_AVG')`  Updated the question with input data

Comment: Reset_index works for index, not columns...

Comment: Okie. Can you help in calculating the sum of second column values(NEWS_SENTIMENT_DAILY_AVG) grouped by year and date.

Comment: I'm not sure I can? because I'm not 100% sure I understand the structure of your dataframe, those columns look bad. Try explicitly reassigning them: `df.columns = ['date', 'avg', 'day', 'month', 'year', ...]` and so on. If you can do that, please update your dataframe, and try my suggestion in my first comment again.

Comment: The problem is your input has a multi-index on its columns: `('EBIX UW Equity', 'NEWS_SENTIMENT_DAILY_AVG')`. If you want to make your life easy, rename the columns as people are suggesting. Otherwise it's a pain for subsequent commands to access columns like `'NEWS_SENTIMENT_DAILY_AVG'`

Answer (score 1):

```py
df = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'], as_index = False).agg('value1':'sum', 'value2':'sum')


news_count = news_count.groupby(['year', 'month'],as_index = False).agg({'NEWS_SENTIMENT_DAILY_AVG':'sum'})
```

Answer (score 0):

extract required columns from dataframe in `news_count_res` variable and then apply aggregation function

```
news_count_res = news_count[['year','month','NEWS_SENTIMENT_DAILY_AVG']]
news_count_res.group(['year','month']).sum()
```

Comment: Thanks for this...but I'm getting "AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'sample'" at "df_sample = df.groupby("persons").sample(frac=percentage_to_flag, random_state=random_state)".  If I can figure out why, maybe it'll work for me...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to answers so far (I've made comments there as I haven't got those solutions to work--maybe I'm not understanding something).  In the meantime, I've also come up with another approach, which I still suspect isn't very Pythonic.  It does get the job done and doesn't take too long for my purposes, but it would be great if I could figure out how to tweak the approaches suggested above to get them to work...any thoughts very welcome!

Here's what I've got:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import math
    y = ['Alex'] * 2321 + ['Doug'] * 34123  + ['Chuck'] * 2012 + ['Bob'] * 9281 
        z = ['xyz'] * len(y)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'persons': y, 'data' : z})
    percent = 10  #CHANGE AS NEEDED

    #add a 'helper'column with random numbers
    df['rand'] = np.random.random(df.shape[0])
    df = df.sample(frac=1)  #optional:  this shuffles data, just to show order doesn't matter

    #CREATE A HELPER LIST
    helper = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('persons')['rand'].count()).reset_index().values.tolist()
    for row in helper:
        df_temp = df[df['persons'] == row[0]][['persons','rand']]
        lim = math.ceil(len(df_temp) * percent * 0.01)
        row.append(df_temp.nlargest(lim,'rand').iloc[-1][1])

    def flag(name,num):
        for row in helper:
            if row[0] == name:
                if num >= row[2]:
                    return 'yes'
                else:
                    return 'no'
    
    df['flag'] = df.apply(lambda x: flag(x['persons'], x['rand']), axis=1)
```

And to check the results:

```
piv = df.pivot_table(index="persons", columns="flag", values="data", aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
piv = piv.apivend(piv.sum().rename('Total')).assign(Total=lambda x: x.sum(1))
piv['% selected'] = 100 * piv.yes/piv.Total
print(piv)

OUTPUT:
flag        no   yes  Total  % selected
persons                                
Alex      2088   233   2321   10.038776
Bob       8352   929   9281   10.009697
Chuck     1810   202   2012   10.039761
Doug     30710  3413  34123   10.002051
Total    42960  4777  47737   10.006913
```

Seems to work with different %s and different numbers of persons...but it would be nice to make it simpler, I think.